# Showing modal dialog when navigating away from a tab in TabStrip

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Is there a way to display a modal dialog when user selects a tab in TabStrip component? The code below displays window.confirm, can not get modal dialog to display.

```
onTabSelected(e : any){
    if (!window.confirm("Continue with navigation?")) {
        e.prevented = true;
    }  
}
```

Comment: in each tab, do you have custom components or html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog is not a direct substitute for `window.confirm`, because it cannot block the UI thread. To substitute the `window.confirm` with the Kendo UI dialog, you can prevent all tab selection, and wait for the dialog result:

```js
onTabSelected(e: any) {
    e.prevented = true;
    this.dialogService.open({
      content: "Continue with navigation?",
      actions: [
        { text: "No" },
        { text: "Yes", primary: true }
      ]
    }).result.subscribe((result) => {
        if (result.primary) {
            // change tab through code
            this.tabStrip.selectTab(e.index);
        }
    });
}
```

See [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EeG5soB0NWqVqlpYX1fH?p=preview) for a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up canceling the tab selection event, showing modal dialog, and resubmitting event based on the user answer.